# Subsonic 3 Simple Repository And Transactions

Tags: subsonic3

So this is what I have so far. Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in 3.0.0.3?

```
    var Repository = new SimpleRepository("DBConnectionName");

    using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (SharedDbConnectionScope scs = new SharedDbConnectionScope("connstring", "providerName"))
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    Supplier s = new Supplier();
                    s.SupplierCode = i.ToString();
                    s.SupplierName = i.ToString();

                    Repository.Add<Supplier>(s);
                }

                ts.Complete();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error in SubSonic DbDataProvider
        public DbConnection CurrentSharedConnection
        {
            get { return __sharedConnection; }

```
        protected set
        {
            if(value == null)
            {
                __sharedConnection.Dispose();
```

etc.. 
__sharedConnection == null :( Object Null Reference Exception :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this for myself.  All of the above code does not work for me (SubSonic 3.0.0.3, using SQLite) but adding `BeginTransaction()` caused it to work as expected, greatly speeding up the transaction and rolling back the updates if any exceptions occur.

```
using (SharedDbConnectionScope sharedConnectionScope = new SharedDbConnectionScope(Access.Provider))
{
    using (IDbTransaction ts = sharedConnectionScope.CurrentConnection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        IRepository repo = new SimpleRepository(Access.Provider);
        //Do your database updates

        //throw new ApplicationException("Uncomment this and see if the updates get rolled back");
        ts.Commit();
    }
}
```

For completeness: `Access.Provider` is a static property in a helper class for me that returns `return SubSonic.DataProviders.ProviderFactory.GetProvider(ConnectionString, "System.Data.SQLite");`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps switching the SharedDbConnectionScope and TransactionScope around may help.

```
using (SharedDbConnectionScope scs = new SharedDbConnectionScope("connstring", "providerName"))
{
    using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will happen when Migration is set - On tablemigration the dbconnection will be closed.

Try the SimpleRepository with SimpleRepositoryOptions.None.

Don't know if this is a bug. I think the transactions don't work with SimpleRepository, I've always half of the data saved when throwing an exception in the transaction... perhaps it's only for ActiveRecord? Anybody knows?